# The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time in Simulator only

Tags: ios, swift

As the title says getting the infamous error

> The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time...

Quite a few SO QAs so my apology if this appears a duplicate but I didn't see any that I found that would help resolve my problem. If I missed please let me know.

The piece of code that it is pointing to is

```
internal static let EaseOutBack = { (elapsed: TimeInterval, duration: TimeInterval) -> Double in
    let s: TimeInterval = 1.70158
    var position: TimeInterval = elapsed / duration
    position -= 1.0
    return Double( position * position * ((s + 1.0) * position + s) + 1.0 )
}
```

Not heavy in any way. Now the thing is this only occurs when attempting to run in a Simulator. Running against a real device it builds fine before running.

Attempts to clean build and restart Xcode/machine before retrying didn't work. Was thinking memory or cache issues.

Thanks ^.^

Comment: `TimeInterval` is a typealias of `Double`. The conversion in the return line is pointless.

Comment: @vadian Thank you. Didn't know that. That was the cause. Removing the conversion resolved it.